# SQL where clause multiple condition on same values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to apply different where condition in SQL based on value of other column something like below.
Sorry,  I am updating my que with more specific requirement

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEDetails 
WHERE CASE WHEN 
    ConfigValue = 'FALSE' THEN 
               (ConfigAmount != 0 OR ConfigVolume != 0)
    WHEN ConfigValue = 'TRUE' THEN
         (ConfigAmount != 0  OR ConfigVolume <Here, it should allow Zero too with other values>
    END
```

Comment: Your edit completely changes your question. Now I don't even understand what you want any more. Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: I have table conatins ConfigAmount and ConfiguVolume with ConfigValue 'True' and 'False'. If ConfigValue is 'False' then it should not allow 0 in ConfigVolume. In both cases it should not allow 0 in ConfigAmount.

Comment: I got that, what means "allow Zero too with other values" ? Allow 0 and some other values, or allow everything ?

Comment: Plus, you should avoid defacing your questions like that, especially when answers already exists. Otherwise, the answers get inaccurate and could confuse future readers.

Comment: yes, true. I want to allow 0 with other values or not.

Comment: - 1) I want to allow 0 and SOME other values, like 1 and 2, but not 3. - 2) I want to allow every value possible for ConfigVolume. Please choose one of the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `AND`s and `OR`s:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEDetails 
WHERE (ConfigValue = 'FALSE' AND ConfigVolume != 0)
   OR (ConfigValue = 'TRUE'  AND ConfigVolume = 0)
```

`CASE WHEN` returns results expressions, and no comparisons like in your query.

As stated by @Pred, a `WHERE` clause must contain comparisons.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

After your edit (which completely changed the requirement BTW), I guess something like this could work, but the question is quite unclear now:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEDetails 
WHERE (ConfigValue = 'FALSE' AND (ConfigAmount != 0 OR ConfigVolume != 0))
   OR (ConfigValue = 'TRUE' AND  (ConfigAmount != 0 OR ConfigVolume IN (0, 1, 2, ... /* add as many values you need*/)))
```

Comment: Nope, you can use `CASE..WHEN` in `WHERE` clause, but you have to **compare** the reult of the clause to another expression (like to a column or to a constant value). The main problem with the original query is that the `WHERE` clause do not contains comprasions.

Comment: @Pred Yeah, I know, I was editing while you were writing your comment... :)

Answer (score 1):

@X.L.Ant wrote a correct and excellent answer, but to complete the list of the possible solutions. Here is one with the `CASE..WHEN` clause:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  TABLEDetails 
WHERE
  ConfigValue = CASE
        WHEN ConfigVolume != 0 THEN 'FALSE'
        WHEN ConfigVolume = 0 THEN 'TRUE'
    END
```

Please note, that the `CASE..WHEN` clause returns `NULL` if there is no `ELSE` condition and none of the `WHEN` conditions are met. (This will filter all records where `ConfigValue < 0` is true, since `NULL` is not equal to anything).

Comment: The logic is the same. @X.L.Ant 's answer is a bit more readable and easier to maintain. I suggest that try to modify his query based on your new requirements.